# does any video portal support mpeg2-ts container format

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, mpeg2-ts

Is there any video portal (such as youtube/youku/hulu) etc, which support mpeg2-ts format ? Just wanted to know if TS format is still in use by any of the content provider.
I know this format is used for media archiving on DVDs etc ... but wanted to know if any content provider uses this format for sending video stream on Internet for live streams or VoD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube supports mpeg2ts container format with H.264/AAC media for HTTP live streaming ... 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnslRRh2wcA ... this URL generates HLS stream.

```
On checking the youtube-dl output found following:
format code extension resolution  note
151         mp4       72p         HLS  (worst)
132         mp4       240p        HLS
92          mp4       240p        HLS
93          mp4       360p        HLS  (best)
```

even though extension says mp4 ... the actual container format used when used through chrome browser on windows is mpeg2ts.